# Empty JDateChooser

Tags: java, jdatechooser

I'm using JDateChooser for a Javaapp (this is the 1st time i use it). I want to catch fault when the JDateChooser is empty with code like this:

```
if(dcs1.getDate().toString().isEmpty()){
       lblOk.setText("Empty");
   }else{
    Date d = dcs1.getDate();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    String t = df.format(d);
    lblOk.setText(t);
   }
JLabel lblOk;
JDateChooser dcs1;
```

But it dont work.
Any1 can help me plzz.

Answer (score 6):

```
Date date;
date = JDateChooser.getDate();

if (date == null) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Choose Date from Right Box.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            JDateChooser.grabFocus();
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
String s = ((JTextField)dateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
if (s.equals("") {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please type birthday", "Warning!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (jDateChooserBirthDate.getDate() == null) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please type birthday", "Warning!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(jDateChooser1.getDate() == null){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Date not selected","No   selection",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    jDateChooser1.requestFocusInWindow();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used DateChooserCombo. and The following code worked for me.

```
String test = dateChooserID.getText();
if(!test.equals("")){
//DO WHATEVER YOU WANT (DATE IS SELECTED IN THIS CASE);
}
else{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "date not choosen");
}
```